# Как вывести абсолютную погрешность, fabs не работает?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a, b, x, y, z, h, d,k;
            Console.Write("a=");
            a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("b=");
            b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("h=");
            h = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("d=");
            d = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (x = a; x <= b; x += h) ;
            {
                k = 1;
                z = 0;
                do
                {
                    y = k * Math.Pow(x, k);
                    z = z + y;
                    k = k++;
                } while (fabs(y) > d);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("x = %f \t", x);
            Console.WriteLine("z = %f \n", z);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Как понимать «fabs не работает»?

Comment: что такое `fabs`? что оно делает или должно делать? Быть может `Math.Abs` надо?

Comment: @tym32167 видимо автор вопроса перешёл на C# с C++, в котором модуль для `double` считается с помощью функции `fabs(...)`  из `math.h`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Помимо того, что функции `fabs()` в C# [нет (есть Abs)](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/20.2.php), в коде есть следующие ошибки:

1. После объявления цикла Вы сразу же ставите точку с запятой, тем самым не давая циклу собственно выполнять код в фигурных скобках;
2. Ввиду особенностей [области видимости переменных](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.18.php) переменная `z` просто так не увидится, особенно если она до этого была не проинициализирована. Я предлагаю, например, в самом начале добавить `z=0`;
3. Конструкция `k = k++` не сработает, ибо она игнорирует `++` постфиксное и по сути присваивает `k` саму себя. Просто `k++` вполне достаточно;
4. Функция [`WriteLine()`](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.15.php) не работает так, как в C, здесь нужно при подстановке переменных писать что-то типа `Console.WriteLine("{0}", a)` или `Console.WriteLine("{a}")`;
5. Я не знаю, с какими именно данными работать, так что у меня всё заработало при смене условия выхода из `do-while`: `while (fabs(y) < d);`

Исходя из этого, примерно хоть какая-то да работающая программа ниже. Я не знаю, соответствует ли она условию задачи или нет, ибо его в условии не было прописано, но, если вкратце: дело было далеко не в `fabs()`...

```cs
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a, b, x, y, z=0, h, d,k;
            Console.Write("a=");
            a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("b=");
            b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("h=");
            h = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("d=");
            d = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (x = a; x <= b; x += h)
            {
                k = 1;
                do
                {
                    y = k * Math.Pow(x, k);
                    z = z + y;
                    k++;
                } while (Math.Abs(y) < d);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("x = {0} \t", x);
            Console.WriteLine("z = {0} \n", z);
        }  
    }
}
```